# Finding count of nodes where two columns are nbsp

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a table where I need to check if two cells, position 9 and 16, are nbsp.  I've had success counting the number of occurrences where position 9 is blank using something like this:

```
    foreach (HtmlNode results in htmlReport.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='tbl1']"))
    {
        countMissingElement = results.SelectNodes("//tr//td[position() = 9 and . = '&nbsp;']").Count;
    }
```

I have tried various iterations of statements similar to the following, but cannot get this to work.

```
countMissingElement = results.SelectNodes("//tr//td[(position() = 9 and . = '&nbsp;') and (position() = 16 and . = '&nbsp;')]").Count;

countMissingElement = results.SelectNodes("//tr//td[(position() = 9 and . = '&nbsp;')] and //tr//td[(position() = 16 and . = '&nbsp;')]").Count;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want to count rows. Therefore, you should select rows where the 9-th and 16-th child fulfill your requirements:

```xml
//tr[td[9]='&nbsp;' and td[16]='&nbsp;']
```

Comment: how can td be at place 9 and 16? I thought you just said that it cannot be both at 9 and 16

Comment: They are different nodes. `td[9]` is the 9-th child of the selected `tr`, `td[16]` is the 16-th child of the selected `tr`. This is different from testing if a single `td` is both at position `9` and `16`.